# I need help with an exercise in my textbook.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $f : A \to B$ be a function, and let $f(A) = \{f(a)$ $|$ $a \in A\}$ be the image of $f$. Show that $f$ is onto if and only if $f(A) = B$.

I'm supposed to write a proof of this problem, but I struggle at proof-writing. any help is very appreciated.

I think it must have to do with $f(a)=b$, $\forall b \in B$. therefore $f$ is onto if and only $f(A)=B$

Let $f$ : $S \to T$ be a function. Then $f$ is said to map S onto T if for each element y $\in$ T there exists an element $x \in S$ with $f(x) = y$. If $f$ maps $S$ onto $T$, then we say that $f$ is an onto function.

Comment: Start by writing down *very carefully* the definition of “$f$ is onto,” paying attention to the quantifiers and orders of words/phrases.

Comment: OK, good. Now rewrite with $A$ and $B$ in the context of your homework. Is every $b\in B$ in $f(A)$?

Comment: Thank You, Ted. Have a great day.

Answer (score 1):

Well you're on the right track but here's the full solution

$f$ is onto $\Longleftrightarrow$ ${\forall}_{b \in B}{\exists}_{a \in A}f(a) = b$

${\forall}_{b \in B}{\exists}_{a \in A}f(a) = b$ $\Longleftrightarrow$ $f(A)= B$

This is because $f(A) = B$ $\Longleftrightarrow$ $b \in B \Longleftrightarrow {\exists}_{a \in A} f(a) = b$

So the statement is $f(A) = B$ is equivalent to the fact that every $b \in B$ is of the form $f(a)$ for some $a \in A$

Which is exactly what ${\forall}_{b \in B}{\exists}_{a \in A}f(a) = b$ means when you translate it into english

"For all $b$ in $B$ there exists a $a$ in $A$ such that $f(a) = b$"

Comment: Thank You. I appreciate it a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $f(A) = B.$

Then for each $b \in B,$ there exists an $a \in A$ such that $f(a) = b.$

This makes $f$ onto $B$.

---

Suppose that $f(A) \neq B.$

Since $f: A\to B$, you must have that $f(A) \subseteq B$.

Therefore, it must be that it is not the case that $B \subseteq f(A)$.

This implies that there exists a $b \in B$, such that $b$ is not an element of $f(A)$.

This implies that there exists a $b \in B$, such that there is no $a \in A$ that satisfies $f(a) = b.$

This implies that $f$ is not onto $B$.

Answer (score 1):

All "if and only if" propositions have two directions, and it's usually sensible (while you're not comfortable with proofs) to attack each direction individually, instead of all at the same time.

The other piece of advice I will give is to be clear about the definitions of what you're dealing with. Note that $f(a) = b, \forall b \in B$ is not entirely clear, since it's not clear what $a$ is. From context, it's clear that you mean:
$$\forall b \in B, \exists a \in A \text{ such that } f(a) = b.$$
Writing it down in full, or perhaps with words, rather than symbols, might help you understand the concept better, and help you logically connect it to $f(A) = B$.

So, the first thing to do is pick a direction. I'm going to assume $f$ is onto, and try to prove $f(A) = B$. Now, it's often a good idea to focus on what you're trying to prove, and that will give you the structure of the proof. In this case, we wish to prove the equality of sets. This opens up two sub-parts of the proof: we need to show $f(A) \subseteq B$, and $B \subseteq f(A)$. That is, we need to prove:

1. Every element of $f(A)$ lies in $B$,
2. Every element of $B$ lies in $f(A)$.

Once again, it's not good to try doing both parts at the same time. Let's concentrate on 1, first.

To prove 1, we start with an arbitrary element $x \in f(A)$. It is our job to follow our noses to the conclusion that $x \in B$. What can we do first? We should investigate what $x \in f(A)$ actually means. What does it mean for something like $x$ to belong to $f(A)$?

According to our definition of $f(A)$, the elements of $f(A)$ take the form $f(a)$, where $a \in A$. What this means is there exists some $a \in A$ such that $x = f(a)$. But, $f$ is a function from $A$ to $B$, so if we put in any value of $a$, the result is in $B$. Thus, $x = f(a) \in B$. This proves 1, and we didn't even need the fact that $f$ was onto.

To prove 2, we once again need an arbitrary element $b \in B$. We now need to show that $b \in f(A)$. That is, there is some $a \in A$ such that $b = f(a)$ (i.e. it takes the form of an element of $f(A)$, according to the definition of $f(A)$). Does this condition look familiar? It's what it means to be onto! The fact that $f$ is onto gives us the $a \in A$ that we need.

To help you, let me cleanly write up the first direction that I explained above:

> Suppose $f$ is onto. We wish to show that $f(A) = B$.
>
> Suppose first that $x \in f(A)$. By definition of $f(A)$, there must exist some $a \in A$ such that $x = f(a)$. As $f : A \to B$, we know $f(a) \in B$. Thus, $x \in B$, hence $f(A) \subseteq B$.
>
> Now, suppose that $b \in B$. As $f$ is onto, there exists some $a \in A$ such that $b = f(a)$. But, $f(a) \in f(A)$, by definition of $f(A)$. Thus, $b \in f(A)$ too, hence $B \subseteq f(A)$.
>
> Together, these two implication tell us that $f(A) = B$.
>
> ....

To complete the proof, the other direction is needed too, but I'll leave that to you. You need to assume that $f(A) = B$. You know you can take any element of $B$, and it will take the form of elements of $f(A)$. But, you should focus on what you're trying to prove: that $f$ is onto. You need to show that, for any $b \in B$, there exists an $a \in A$ such that $f(a) = b$. You will need the assumption to get to the end of the proof.